# What will explode if I import `pprint()` over `print()`?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I notice that I can do this and get away with it, at least at first glance:

`from pprint import pprint as print`

Convenient. But I have a bad feeling about this. What sort of grue is going to eat me if I try this in a nontrivial program?

Comment: They don't have the same API, *any* use of print that isn't just a single argument will choke. Multiple arguments, using sep and end, ...

Comment: I mean, it will only affect the module you imported from...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing will explode, because this import will only change your local [namespace](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/this.py#L21).

> Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

You may go ahead and do it, without fear of breaking other namespaces or being eaten by grues.

Do be aware, however, that the [`pprint` call signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) is different from `print`, so it's possible some `print` lines within the containing module may need to be adjusted.  My recommendation is to import it under the usual name, `pprint`, and use the find/replace features of your text editor to change existing `print` calls accordingly.

Comment: I mean... You say nothing bad will happen and then explain how something bad could happen and how to avoid it.

Comment: Hmm, no, I can't agree with that - nothing bad will happen. Name shadowing is a *feature*.

Comment: It's a feature that has consequences. OP was asking about what those consequences were. You started your answer with "Nothing". Which just seemed, to me, a strange way to introduce an explanation of what the consequences were.

Comment: I am charitably assuming all the prints in OP's module are data structures such as dicts and the OP actually wants them pretty-printed. "Nothing" was intended to contract "Nothing (will explode if you overwrite the name print)", have edited to that effect...

Answer (score 5):

Beware that `pprint` is meant for dumping Python data structures, as it always prints the output of the `__repr__` method of each object in the data structures pass to it, and is therefore not very suitable as a replacement to `print`:

```
>>> b = '''Hemingway's "The Old Man and the Sea"'''
>>> print(b)
Hemingway's "The Old Man and the Sea"
>>> pprint(b)
'Hemingway\'s "The Old Man and the Sea"'
```

So if you replace the built-in `print` function with `pprint` and want to print some readable messages, you would find the output looking funny with all these unintended quotes and escape sequences.